# How can i make use this code html +php

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi i am trying to get the custom post category name within my loop , i have two catagory ,   How can i use this html attribute inside my php tag  can someone help me on this . 
if cat consol is get selected this need to show some custome post contnet, if that not need to select the second item.

```
<section id="startups">
        <div class="container container-fullWidth">
            <div class="sectionContent">

             <?php
          $loop=new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'startup',
                                   'sort_column' => 'post_date',
                                    'posts_per_page'=> -1 
                                    //'order' => 'DESC'
                                    )
                            ); 
        if ( $loop->have_posts() ) 
        {
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) 
              {
                $loop->the_post();
                ?>

                <h2 class="sectionHeader"> <p class ="post_title">STARTUPS</p><span class="borderBottom"></span></h2>
                <div class="row startupSec">
                    <div class="col-lg-12" id="start">
                        <!-- <div class="ls-nav-left-arrow"><a href="#"></a></div> -->

                        <!----startup button---->
                        <div class="row">
                            <section class="color-1">
                                <div class="cl-effect-20">
                                    <?php 
                                    $cat=get_post_meta($post->ID,'category',true);
                                      if ($cat=='console')
                                     {
                                        echo "<div class="startupbutton col-lg-offset-4 col-lg-2 col-md-offset-3 col-md-3 col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-4 ">
                                        <a><span class="orangeBtn" id="lilleSliderBtn" data-hover="LILLE">LILLE</span></a>
                                        <span class="radtypecircle" id="lilleRadio"></span>";?>

                                  <?php  echo"div" ?>
                                 }
                          else if ($cat=='consol2')
                             {
                                   <?php
                                    echo "<div class="startupbutton col-lg-2  col-md-3 col-sm-4">
                                        <a><span class="orangeBtn" id="parisSliderBtn" data-hover="PARIS">PARIS</span></a>";?>

                                  <?php  echo"</div>" ?>
                                  <?php
                              }
                              ?>
```

Comment: What error do you get, what happens with this code?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'startupbutton' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\as\wp-content\themes\IES\index.php on line 135

Comment: thanks for your reply , my question is am i using the correct way of html attribute inside the php tag , i am really unclear with this!!!

In the above  you can find error start from "  echo "<div class="startupbutton"  "

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, how you use strings.

You can `echo` something, or you can store something in a variable, when you use double or single quotes.

When you use one of them, then the first quote is the starting quote, the second is the terminating. If you want to use double quote in double quote, or simple quote in simple quote, you need to escape the quotes in the content.

For example:

```
echo "Double quote here: \" in the content";
```

With the backslash character,  you can escape it.

```
echo 'This is good " also'
```

No need to escape, because the start / end string is different.

So you need to use it like this:

```
echo '<div class="startupbutton col-lg-offset-4 col-lg-2 col-md-offset-3 col-md-3 col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-4 ">';
```

I am using single quote at start / end of the string.

Use a good IDE like NetBeans, Eclipes, PHPStrom, etc... to discover syntax errors like this.